# One anchor tag is not working on Firefox, but works fine on Google, cant find out why

Tags: html, css, button, cross-browser

Well I have recently made a website for local veterinarian and everything worked out fine except this one anchor tag that for some reason is not working on Firefox, but works fine on Chrome. I cant seem to find the reason why..

Link to Website https://www.petvetbihac.com/

```
<section id="home">
  <div class="home">
    <div class="home__content">
      <img src="assets/img/logo/logo.png" class="home__content--logo img-fluid" alt="logo">
      <div class="title__underline"></div>
      <p class="home__content--text">Samostalna veterinarska praksa u Bihaću</p>

      <a href="#about" class="customBtn smooth-scroll">Više O nama</a>

    </div>
```

CSS FOR ANCHOR TAG:

```
.customBtn {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: $color-white;
    background: $color-secondary;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
    border: 2px solid $color-secondary;
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;

    @media only screen and (max-width:$bp-small-3) {
        font-size: 1.7rem;   
    }

    &:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
        background: $color-primary;
        border: 2px solid $color-primary;
        color: $color-white;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    &__footer {
        font-size: 1.4rem;
        background: white;
        color: $color-primary;
        border: 2px solid $color-primary;
        @media only screen and (max-width:$bp-small-3) {
            padding: .2rem .5rem; 
        }

        &:hover {
            background: $color-secondary;
            color: white;
            border: 2px solid $color-secondary;
        }
    }

    &__home {
        animation-name: moveInBottom;
        animation-duration: 1s;
        animation-timing-function: ease-out;

    }
    &__work {
        background: $color-secondary;
        color: $color-white;
        height: 4rem;

        &:hover {
            background: $color-primary-dark;
            color: $color-white !important;
            border: 2px solid $color-primary-dark; 
        }
    }
  }
```

No error messages.

Comment: you should validate your html, probably an unclosed tag somewhere

Comment: I validated html, its not it. Fixed some of minor mistakes but still not working.

Comment: Then you need to create a [mcve] in the question - [not just post a link to your website](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Thank you Pete. You are really helpful.

Comment: Sarcasm won't get you any help, if you don't want to follow the rules of the site, then don't expect any help.  Creating an example in your question is for 2 main reasons - 1) this is a repository of information for future users so if you bothered to read the link you would see once you have fixed your problem, this question would be of no use to future visitors; 2) the act of recreating the error can help point you to your error

Comment: Well Pete I posted the HTML and CSS code not only link to my site like you claim. Please enlighteen me to how to make example of this odd situation where every anchor tag on the site works fine on all browsers but just one does not work on Firefox ? I posted this in hope that someone else had a similar situation to point me in the direction of the problem, because I have no clue where to even start.

Answer (score 0):

If you raise `z-index` of that button, it seems working in Firefox.